# how to launch files from sd card in uwp?

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-mobile

I'm trying to create a file explorer for windows 10 mobile
I need to launch files with default app from pathes (not installed directory)
ex. "d:\test.pdf" 
Here's what I've tried:

```
string p = @"a.jpg";
StorageFolder externalDevices = Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.RemovableDevices; 
StorageFile file = await externalDevices.GetFileAsync(p); 
var success = await Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(fff);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We are a question-and-answer site, not a coders-for-hire service. Please explain what you have tried so far and why it hasn't worked.

Comment: what I have tried:  

string p = @"a.jpg";
StorageFolder externalDevices = Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.RemovableDevices;
StorageFile file = await externalDevices.GetFileAsync(p);
var success = await Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(fff);

Answer (score 0):

you can use [Windows.System.Launcher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br241801) API to launch the default handler for a file you can read more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/launch-the-default-app-for-a-file)

```
async void DefaultLaunch()
  {
     // Path to the file in the app package to launch
string imageFile = @"images\test.png";

var file = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync(imageFile);

if (file != null)
{
  // Launch the retrieved file
  var success = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(file);

  if (success)
  {
     // File launched
  }
  else
  {
     // File launch failed
  }
 }
  else
   {
   // Could not find file
   }
 }
```

Comment: tnx but as I told I want launch files from sd card like a file manager...
I tried this code but this just work in installed directory

Comment: @Milad.P You can access files and folders by letting the user interact with a picker. You can use the FileOpenPicker and FileSavePicker classes to access files, and the FolderPicker to access a folder. you can read more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/quickstart-using-file-and-folder-pickers)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access files from SD card, please make sure that you have read the [What you can and can't access on the SD card](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/access-the-sd-card#what-you-can-and-cant-access-on-the-sd-card) section on document.

> Your app can only read and write files of file types that the app has registered to handle in the app manifest file.
>   Your app can also create and manage folders.
>   Make sure that you check "Removable Storage" in the capabilities of the appxmanifest.

You must declare a file type association in the Package.appxmanifest in order to read files from the SD card. The following is an example of one that I set up:

[image]

Then, I used the following code sample to launch a picture which is contained in "New folder" on SD card successfully.

```
string p = @"1.jpg";
StorageFolder externalDevices = Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.RemovableDevices;
var rootfolder = (await externalDevices.GetFoldersAsync()).FirstOrDefault();
var folder = await rootfolder.GetFolderAsync("New folder");
var file = await folder.GetFileAsync(p); 
var success = await Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(file);
```